Usagestatsmanager(queryEvents) API giving incorrect data for screen time usage
my kotlin code is written to get screen time data of all apps between 11 am today and yesterday.
val usageStatsManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val endTime = calendar.timeInMillis
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24)
val startTime = calendar.timeInMillis

val usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(startTime, endTime)


I am calculating the app usage by the time difference between UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED and UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED.
However for certain android devices this returns incorrect data. Suppose I use an App from 1 pm to 2 pm. I will have data that says app usage from 1 pm to 2 pm, 1 30 pm to 1 45 pm, 1 50 pm to 2 10 pm. This is absurdly incorrect. There are even cases where I will have app usage data for the entire night when the user is sleeping i.e. 11 pm to 7 am. How should I fix this issue?

"I will have data that says app usage" -- please edit your question and provide the code for how you are determining "app usage", given the UsageEvents that queryEvents() returns. "This is absurdly incorrect" -- why? "There are even cases where I will have app usage data for the entire night when the user is sleeping" -- apps can run in the background, such as periodic jobs via WorkManager.

@CommonsWare It is incorrect because If I am using app between 1 pm and 2 pm without closing it, how can there be another usage event from 1 50 pm to 2 10 pm. I am calculating the app usage by the time difference between UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED and UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED. So I should not have data of app usage which occurs in background.

A UsageEvent.Event is an "event representing a state change for a component". If you use an app between 1-2pm, there will be a state change around 2pm. So, seeing one or more usage events between 1:50-2:10pm seems reasonable. "I am calculating the app usage by the time difference..." -- perhaps there is a bug in that code. Or, since you mention "certain android devices", perhaps there is something unusual about those devices that impacts your interpretation of the events.
